# Find the set of points on the complex plane for which $z^2 + z + 1$ is real and positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> **Find the set of points on the complex plane for which $z^2 + z + 1$ is  real and positive.**
>
> For being real I applied the condition: $z^2 + z + 1=\bar{z}^2 +
>  \bar{z} + 1$
>
> For the expression to be positive I applied:
>
> $z^2+z+1>0 \implies (z+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2})(z+\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2})>0 \implies z \in (-\infty,\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}] \cup [\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2},\infty)$

But my doubt is it won't be correct to say $z$ is larger or smaller than a particular complex number as that makes no sense. What will be the correct method of solving this problem?

Comment: Hint: $z^2+z+1=(z+1/2)^2+3/4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=a+ib$: 
$$z^2+z+1=(a^2-b^2+a+1+i2ab)+(a+ib)+1=a^2+b^2+a+1+ib(1+2a)$$
This is real if $1+2a=0\Rightarrow a=-\frac 12$

i.e. $$z=-\frac 12+ib$$

On the complex plane $(x,y)$, the set of points is $$x=-\frac 12\qquad\blacksquare$$.

NB: $z^2+z+1=\frac 34-b^2$.

---

The above result can be derived directly from @Wowoju's very useful hint above.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^2+z+1=k,\ k>0$$
$$z^2+z+(1-k)=0$$
$$z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot1\cdot(1-k)}}{2\cdot1}$$
$$z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4k-3}}2\tag1$$
When $0<k<\frac34$, $\sqrt{4k-3}$ is imaginary and $z=-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt{3-4k}}2i$; the range of the imaginary part is $(-\frac{\sqrt3}2,\frac{\sqrt3}2)$. When $k\ge\frac34$, $\sqrt{4k-3}$ is real and $z$ is given by $(1)$; its range is the whole real line.

In conclusion, the range of $z$ for which $z^2+z+1$ is real and positive is
$$\Bbb R\cup\{-\tfrac12+ai\mid a\in(-\tfrac{\sqrt3}2,\tfrac{\sqrt3}2)\}$$